# Check WiFi signal strength on client using (Chrome Browser, Ubuntu OS)

Tags: javascript

I want to print WiFi signal strength of my client laptop in the browser. Can I do that using JavaScript? I could not find anything online. Even the status of WiFi being connected or disconnected would work. But I need to see that in browser (Chrome in this case).

Answer (score 2):

You can't. This information is not exposed to the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation

Only available on Android and some advertised metrics seem to not show up but better than nothing.