# How to detect and display WiFi signal strength using vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wifi

I want detect and display Wi-Fi signal strength using vanilla JavaScript. I know I can tell [whether someone is online or offline with JavaScript](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=javascript&file=detect-internet-connection-status), but I want to do more and show the usual bars depending on the signal strength.

Also, a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213644/how-calculate-bandwidth-of-the-wifi-or-wifi-signal-strength-using-jquery-or-java) (not identical, similar) has been asked seven years ago on stackoverflow, but things have changed in JavaScript since then so the answer might be different.

From [what I read](https://www.metageek.com/training/resources/wifi-signal-strength-basics.html), I understand that what I need is a dBm (decibels relative to a milliwatt) value.

Edit: The platforms I'm working with are Windows and Android. If this is not doable with vanilla JS, then I can use an external library.

Comment: On which platform?

Comment: Potentially a duplicate of [_Check WiFi signal strength on client using (Chrome Browser, Ubuntu OS)_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33224445/check-wifi-signal-strength-on-client-using-chrome-browser-ubuntu-os)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation

is what  I could find... apparently the only exposure of that still is within Android...

at that point MAYBE... something could be done with react.native... which is not 'vanilla'... so berg...

but I would maybe cheat... maybe you can do something with a call to a python script... or .bat/.sh file?

Comment: well... reading though that doc again... maybe it just needs webworkers, not android specifically. in that case it should be pretty easy. just spawn a webworker and have it run one of those methods on an interval or so, send the data back to the main.js file... if that's the case...

Comment: I just updated my question above.